# display: none; to display: block; won't work

Tags: html, css

So, I have this list where only the first item in the list is visible. I want to be able to see other items when I hover on the first item. bellow is my code but it doesn't work. After hovering, nothing happens.

This is the list:

```css
#manage {
  float: right;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
#manage li {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: Aqua;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
}
#header ul a {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: White;
}
.sub {
  margin-top: 3px;
  display: none;
}
li:hover .sub {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul id="manage">
  <li><a href="#">managment</a>
  </li>
  <li class="sub"><a href="#">Add</a>
  </li>
  <li class="sub"><a href="#">Edit</a>
  </li>
  <li class="sub"><a href="#">Account</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `li:hover .sub` is a `.sub` within the `li`, not adjacent. (And you can't hover over something that's not displayed in the first place.)

Comment: the first item is displayed.

Comment: yes, so when you hover over the first item, any entries in the first item that were hidden and have the class `.sub` will get displayed. (But you don't have any of those.) The space between the `li` and the `.sub` makes a huge difference, from a `li` than contains something wtih class `sub` to a `li` that has itself class `sub`

Comment: put the elements in the `sub` class in an unordered list placed in the first `list-item`.I have tried it myself and seems to provide what you need.Check out in the answer

Comment: so .sub should be within the first item? i tried it but didn't work either

Comment: No It should be in the `ul` which is in the first list item, Just try to copy and paste the code I've given you.

Comment: You should create a new `<ul class="sub">` tag and put it into `<li>` tag. That's @UlrichSchwarz mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One minor adjustment to your CSS can get this to work.

If you target your first `li` for the hover, not only does the current CSS selector attempt to select child elements rather than sibling elements, but your elements are going to immediately disappear when you hover over any of the now visible `li` elements, so re-target your CSS selector to your parent `ul#manage` element.

```
#manage:hover  .sub
{
    display:block;
}
```

```css
#manage
{
    float:right;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
#manage li
{
    width:100px;
    height:30px;
    background-color:Aqua;
    text-align:center;
    list-style-type:none;
}

#header ul a
{
    font-size:25px;
    font-weight:normal;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:White;
}

.sub 
{
    margin-top:3px;
    display:none;
}
#manage:hover > .sub
{
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<ul id="manage">
        <li><a href="#">managment</a></li>
        <li class="sub"><a href="#">Add</a></li>
        <li class="sub"><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
        <li class="sub"><a href="#">Account</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: Ok. this is perfect for me even better than the first answer. thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding those list items in an unordered list inside the first list item

```
<ul id="manage">
    <li><a href="#">managment</a>
        <ul class="sub">
             <li><a href="#">Add</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Account</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

And in your css

```
.sub 
{
    margin-top:3px;
    display:none;
}
li:hover .sub
{
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much. it worked!! i can't vote up though i don't have enough reputation

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is in the last rule:

```
li:hover .sub
```

Try instead:

```
ul:hover li.sub
```